# service fabric client just exits

Tags: wcf, azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I've built an azure service fabric app/service which caches objects. Now with the code below I made a client in a console window which calls the service.
When putting a breakpoint on c.Add and then stepping over it the program just exits. No exception is thrown, "done" is not printed, the program just exits with code 0.
The service is running and is in healthy state. What can I do to find out whats wrong?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test();
    }

    static async void Test()
    {
        Uri serviceName = new Uri("fabric:/CacheApp/PreorderCache");
        ServicePartitionResolver resolver = new ServicePartitionResolver(() => new System.Fabric.FabricClient());
        NetTcpBinding binding = (NetTcpBinding)WcfUtility.CreateTcpClientBinding();

        Client c = new Client(new WcfCommunicationClientFactory<IPreorders>(binding, null, resolver), serviceName, 1);

        try
        {
            PreOrder po = await c.Get("50", "11001", OrderNumber = "123456" });
            Console.WriteLine("done");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

After investigation it seems to have something to do with the transaction being used inside the service.

The service never gets past

```
await tx.CommitAsync();
```

here's the faulting code in the service, nothing special

```
await preOrders.GetAsync(tx, d, s, (k, v) => preOrder);
ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this, "after update");
await tx.CommitAsync();
ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this, "after commit");
```

Answer (score 1):

`Test` is an async method that is not awaited from `Main`. So your program doesn't wait for `Test` to complete.

Adding the `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` makes your `Test` method act like a regular method, that blocks until `c.Get()` has completed.

So use option 2, and remove 'async'.

(And reserve the use of [async void](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) to async eventhandlers.)